# How to connect my app to SocketIO server if i have CORS enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, socket.io, flutter-web

I'm trying to connect my Flutter APP to my SocketIO server (v2), if I enable cors

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
    origins: ["http://localhost:5500", "*", "*:*"]
})
```

It shows this error (on Android Studio)

```
I/flutter (20998): reconnect_error: WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://192.168.1.8:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket
```

If I disable cors it works perfectly, but I need cors because I need to be able to connect my test file (chat.html) that runs on localhost:5500, and in the future, connect my Flutter Web App

Comment: Well hello, I think you should just remove origins from your io options and use io.origins() callback to determine who can connect who can't =)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the answer that works for me

Comment: Remember that `io.origins` doesn't supported after v2 :) glad that worked!

Comment: No, but I user the allowRequest function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
    allowRequest: (req, callback) => {
        const origin = req.headers.origin
        const origins = [
            undefined,
            "http://localhost:5500",
            "http://127.0.0.1:5500"
        ]
        callback(null, origins.includes(origin))
    }
})
```

(This works only for v2)